# solution of system of coupled partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following system of coupled differential equations:

$\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}=b~\frac{\partial^{2}f(x,t)}{\partial x^{2}}-k~f(x,t)+g~ c(x,t)$

$\frac{\partial c(x,t)}{\partial t}=k~f(x,t)-g~c(x,t)$

with $f(x,0)=a$ and $c(x,0)=0$. The corresponding mathematica code is:

```
DSolve[{D[f[x, t], t] == b D[f[x, t], {x, 2}] - k f[x, t] + g c[x, t], 
D[c[x, t], t] == k f[x, t] - g c[x, t], f[x, 0] == a, c[x, 0] == 0},
{f[x,t], c[x,t]}, {x, t}]
```

But the mathematica returns the code itself. Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure an analytical solution exists?

Comment: Could you include more context for this coupled set of equations?  What physics are you trying to demonstrate or solve?  That may help.  Looks to be a non-homogeneous heat equation where the the (convection) term $g\, c(x,t)$ shows coupled behaviour?  Boundary conditions would help too.

Comment: This is a linear set of reaction-diffusion equations - could come from linearizing a nonlinear set as in stability analysis for Turing patterns?  Anyhow, you probably do need boundary conditions as @drN suggests.  Since your initial conditions are spatially homogeneous, the diffusion term is zero, so in its current form you could change to a set of ODEs.

Comment: @ChrisK Linear system or rxn-dfsn equation: could have Soliton solutions/Tanh method (analytical)?

Comment: @drN I don't know about that. It should depend on BCs.  Maybe a sum of  $e^{ikx+\lambda_kt}$ terms works?  Check [this](http://www.cmp.caltech.edu/~mcc/BNU/Notes7_2.pdf) out for example.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation on my user to add a comment, but by on the second equation using the respective integration factor for c, you can build an expression for the function f, using that f on the first equation you would have to build a single third-order PDE that depends on the behavior of the function c allowing that way an analytical solution of your system, sorry for not giving a more detailed answer but I'm kinda Noob on this page. good luck with everything.

Answer (score 1):

I introduced two boundary conditions on $x$ which are

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}f(0,t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}f(L,t) = 0
$$

to facilitate the Laplace Transform technique. Using the Laplace transformation

```
Clear[f, c, t, x]
eqn = {D[f[x, t], t] - b D[f[x, t], {x, 2}] + k f[x, t] - g c[x, t] == 0, D[c[x, t], t] - k f[x, t] + g c[x, t] == 0};
ic = {f[x, 0] == a, c[x, 0] == b};
bc = {Derivative[1, 0][f][0, t] == Derivative[1, 0][f][L, t] == 0};
teqn = Flatten[LaplaceTransform[{eqn, bc}, t, s] /. Rule @@@ ic /. HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a]
```

after that, extracting and substituting  $c(x,t)$

```
solc = Solve[teqn[[2]], c[x, t]][[1]]
eqnf = teqn[[1]] /. solc
```

Solving for $x$

```
tsol = f[x, t] /. First@DSolve[{eqnf, bc}, f[x, t], x] // FullSimplify
```

and finally determining $f(x,t)$

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[tsol, s, t]
```

after that, $c(x,t)$ is straightforward.

NOTE

Depending on the boundary conditions, the Laplace inversion could be not easily obtained, in which case a residues solution can be an alternative.